# Best method to dispose of an unused security token?

Tags: php, security, authorization

I have implemented a security system in a project I'm working on , as follows (please tell me if something is unclear in the diagram, its simple though)

[image: chart]

This is working exactly like it should, but if someone makes a request, and aborts it as soon as the token has been received on client side, then the active token will still be in database, and can be used maliciously by a hacker.

Although I delete the tokens from database in verifyToken step, but if the token hasn't reached it, it will still be usable. What do you guys think will be the method to dispose of the token if the request was aborted after token being issued?

Also, even if the clients gains access to a token, he can make only one request before the token is flagged invalid. But still , even one request can be highly dangerous.

***UPDATE*** : My token mechanism is as follows :

**Sending a token :**

1)Generate 2 random tokens : token1 and token2.

2)Generate a hash like this : token1+userid+SALT

3)Store all data in a databse.

4)Send token1, token2, and the new hash (i call it id_hash)

**Verifying a token :**

1)Receive token1 and token2.

2)If token2 does not match with that from database, return FALSE.

3)Get user id from session.

4)Hash it in the following order : token1(received) + userid (session) + SALT

5) Verify the newly verified hash with the id_hash received.

6) If matches, return TRUE, else return FALSE.

This way, a user can access/change only that data which is related to his userid, and not other user's ids.
Do you guys think this is enough? Or are there flaws to this method?

I'm using PHP, and MySQL, on apache2 webserver.

Comment: how many times a unique token can makes request?

Comment: @fortune considering that the tokens get deleted in verifyToken step, I'd say that they can be used only once.

Comment: by the way, dispose-of, not dispose-off

Comment: @CreativeMind typo :P

Comment: inside your post too... :P

Comment: @CreativeMind more typos :P

Comment: you can make a status flag for the token. Once the token is making a request, you can verify it and put the status flag to accessed. So next time, the token is making request you can check the status of the token that it is a new request or old one and process accordingly.

Comment: That is indeed what is already happening. But the question is. What happens if a token `doesn't` make a request, and stays on client side? That is, the user aborted the request after token was received.

Answer (score 0):

When sending the token store a random string on the client side to use as a salt (well not a salt a random check)

As all requests should occur within a session send this random string along with requests to verify that you are talking to the correct client (send at first stage - request token then verify against this token at verification).

This obviously doesn't stop anyone from intercepting the message but if they got the unused token it would be useless without the random string as a second test.

Additionally add a timestamp to your tokens - if they aren't verified within say 10 seconds of being created make them invalid.

Comment: I see. Although, I already do that part. But to send the string along with the request, we have to include it in the form. Doesn't that make it visible to the attacker?
And what if the correct client is himself/herself the attacker? Then he can use that token anywhere, as long as he knows what the token is...

Comment: Yes but your question wasn't about how to secure the connection against interception - that should be done with SSL certificate. The above ensure the validity of your token - destroy all tokens each hour / night through a cron job as they should be short-lived.

Comment: I do have a SSL certificate, and all the connections are encrypted. Also, see updated question. And I do have a cron job, which deletes all tokens that have been inactive for 10 mins.

Comment: Your way will work and will be sufficiently secure (you will most likely have more vulnerabilities elsewhere than in this authorisation system) - but what is wrong with oAuth - http://oauth.net/code/ - seeing as it is industry standard and works pretty much straight out of the box I don't see why you are doing this other than for a learning exercise?

Comment: although most users would accept your suggestion, i do not. I want to dive into the fundamentals of these security systems. And yes this is mainly for educational purposes, but I plan on making my ways rock solid. Thanks for the suggestions though! (I'll keep asking important things on stackoverflow :P)

Comment: Well I feel I have answered your original and ammended question sufficiently - I often make things for educational purposes also - BUT I will always compare to industry standard as they have been made by people who are a) smarter than me and b) thousands of unit tests a single person cannot achieve alone - finding vulnerabilities that you would not think of - I would dissect the oAuth library now as your way is as robust as you are going to make it alone - a +1 would be great if I helped if you don't feel you can accept my answer!!!

Comment: you're getting me wrong. I do accept your answer, and am very thankful to you and all people who are always here to help other less experienced people like me. +1 for `I will always compare to industry standard` . I would also do that, but only when I have to secure a client's application. This is a personal project, and I want to have my own logic implemented (even if there are people smarter than me, and they surely exist, millions of them). oAuth sure is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well Here is My way to do it.

I'll re-validate and regenerate tokens say after every 3 minutes.

and before processing any request made by that token I'll check if it is valid or not.

That'll automatically in-validate the older tokens.

Second Way:

`TimeStamp`: Use Time stamp to check validity of that token. If that token makes no activity for say last 3 minutes then invalidate that toke. for that you'll need a `cron job` to make that script run every specific interval of time.

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: I see. But what if I send a token on page load, and it stays there until user makes a request? If the user does not make any request for, say 5 minutes, then his/her token will be expired and he/she will see an error?

Comment: @abhishek You can keep connection alive using `Ajax`, So even if User doesn't makes request you can make it in your script.

Comment: wouldn't keeping the connection alive be a bigger flaw? As if the attacker gains access, he can maliciously use that connection right?

Comment: if you use `Session` with this method to validate then it is really hard for attacker to use `session hijacking`.

Comment: Updated question, sorry, typo :P